# 'Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)'When training CNN in keras using tensorflow as backend

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, stack-overflow

the framing of my CNN is like:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(100, 60, activation='relu', input_shape=(20000, 1), padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(4))
model.add(Conv1D(50, 4, activation='relu', input_shape=(20000, 1), padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(400, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(11, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

and it is running well in this way.
but as long as i change the activation of Conv1D into **'tanh'** or compile the network by **loss='binary_crossentropy'**, and then train it with the same data i use as before,it always ended up with the error mentioned in the title.like this:

```
Epoch 1/10
2021-05-17 14:36:36.874241: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-05-17 14:36:37.480957: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:334] Loaded cuDNN version 8005
2021-05-17 14:36:38.097830: W tensorflow/stream_executor/gpu/redzone_allocator.cc:314] Internal: ptxas exited with non-zero error code -1, output: 
Relying on driver to perform ptx compilation. 
Modify $PATH to customize ptxas location.
This message will be only logged once.
2021-05-17 14:36:38.138281: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-05-17 14:36:38.800945: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-05-17 14:36:38.856575: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1838] TensorFloat-32 will be used for the matrix multiplication. This will only be logged once.
Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)
```

It looks very strange to me,hopefully someone can help me out.

my GPU is RTX3060 desktop 6G;cuda==11.1.114, cudnn==8;tensorflow==2.4.0

Comment: what are the problems set like, data set x, y?

Comment: thx for your comment! x_train is (5959, 20000) binary data, and y_train is (5959,11) binary data. it is actually a protein subcellular localization problem.

Comment: @Xcoppliaga, Can you downgrade `CUDA` drive to `11.0` from `11.1.114` and try? According Tensorflow tested build configuration compatible version for `TF 2.4` is `CUDA 11.0` and `cuDNN 8.0`. For more information you can refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu). Thanks!

Comment: If you are sure, that path to `ptxas` is already in `$PATH`.You can enable explicit logging for the `PTX` compiler by adding set `TF_CPP_VMODULE="asm_compiler=3"` before running the code. For more information you can refer [this](https://dobromyslova.medium.com/making-work-tensorflow-with-nvidia-rtx-3090-on-windows-10-7a38e8e582bf). Thanks!